# What would Martian Life be like?

Tags: internal-consistency, xenobiology, genetic-engineering, planets, ecology

Basically what I'm asking is how would hypothetical life be able to survive on Mars? Would they need to be created from scratch in some effort to make life on seemingly uninhabitable worlds or partially cybernetic to withstand the harsh Martian environment?

Or would I need to tweak the Martian environment to more habitable levels, such as setting up a slightly thicker atmosphere and adding on some liquid water (which would also require a thicker atmosphere, as well as an magnetosphere too in order to keep the atmosphere from being blown off)?

I'm also half considering either it being humanity seeding life on Mars as opposed to them evolving on it themselves. However I would prefer to see if they could just organically grow on Mars without any outside interference, however I will accept if they must be influenced somewhat by outsiders or planted there with special modifications to survive on it.

What kind of traits would I expect out of them? Thicker fur and hides? More eyes? Would I need to give these new creatures some sort of cybernetics to survive on it or could they just live on Mars as it currently is without cybernetics?

I want to do the least changes to the current Martian Environment, but I would not be too opposed to doing the above if it proves to be too difficult for a mostly biological creature to handle. I would mainly want for a land animal, however an oceanic suggestion would also be accepted as well.

Comment: Sorry to have to say it, but this is hugely broad. Basically the only restrictions are ‘life’ and ‘mars’. Could you think of a more specific kind of life you’re interested in and ask about the viability of that?

Comment: Noted down, I'll be thinking about any specifics in animals and such as just mentioning "Animal-life" would also be too broad as well.

Thanks for the tip, I'll make sure to try specifying more in the future.

Comment: Lichens, lots and lots of lichens.

Comment: Seems like an interesting addition to the plantlife on that world. Will try to consider how that might work into a larger ecology if there would be any.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### There's an outside chance complex ocean life is there already:

The thin atmosphere basically rules out out anything air breathing, unless in a sealed underground cavern that's totally self sustaining, but that's fairly unlikely. However there are some really interesting places complex life could hypothetically exist without any changes to Mars at all:

There are [big lakes underground on Mars](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&source=web&rct=j&url=https://www.australiangeographic.com.au/news/2018/07/underground-lake-discovered-on-mars/&ved=2ahUKEwj6iJnWqq_sAhXGXSsKHdwCB-wQFjAfegQIZRAB&usg=AOvVaw0lRMVLwz4-MFFU_FIEc1-n), full or salt and perchlorates which are toxic to us, but may be home to a few hypothetical types of marine life.

It's doubtful the water has dissolved oxygen in it, which rules out fish with gills breathing oxygen as we know them (but we don't know - it could?). We have [lifeforms gathering around vents on the ocean floor living off dissolved hydrogen and sulfur](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&source=web&rct=j&url=http://ocean.si.edu/ecosystems/deep-sea/microbes-keep-hydrothermal-vents-pumping%3Famp&ved=2ahUKEwjK4MHbrK_sAhWRfH0KHZI4A8YQFjACegQICRAF&usg=AOvVaw1LwCCl74QVq8H_JfAjMnb-&ampcf=1), so who knows the true limits of biology - anything is really possible. There's no reason lifeforms like these couldn't have evolved into a complex tadpole or fish or crab like creature. The physics of motion through water and predator prey dynamics would be similar, so anything you see deep in earth's oceans there's an outside possibility something similar looking may be found in subsurface Martian oceans.

#### There may also be complex burrowing animals. Ant like.

You also have have soil to borrow in. There's the possibility of tiny bacteria, which could extend even to small insect or worm like lifeforms burrowing deep within the soil, staying away from the surface and the nasty radiation and temperatures. You could have ant colonies or similar things, they would need a source of oxygen to breath (perhaps dissolving rocks?), or some form of photosynthesis, or perhaps the could depend on  some other biology.